# Como crear un array de objetos apartir de parametros de otro array para mandarlo a una API. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, estructuras-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Lo que quiero hacer es que el Array carrito lo quiero recorrer ese array y extraer algunos parametros: product_id, data: [] y cantidad, en otro nuevo arreglo para mandarlo a una API de crear una orden,

Comment: puedes poner el texto del código? en imagen no es muy agradable para muchos en el sitio. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que quieres utilizar, puedes usar la función `.map()` de los arrays ([más info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)), que lo que hace es recorrer todo el array y aplicar la función callback a cada elemento. En esa función recibida como parámetro estamos creando un objeto por cada elemento, que se irá asignando al nuevo array `seleccion`:

```js
const carrito = [
 { product_id: 1, combo: null, data: [], price: 100, quantity: 1 },
 { product_id: 2, combo: null, data: [3], price: 80, quantity: 2 },
 { product_id: 3, combo: null, data: [8, 2], price: 120, quantity: 1 },
];

const seleccion = carrito.map(product => ({
  product_id: product.product_id,
  data: product.data,
  quantity: product.quantity
}));

console.log('Tu selección actual: ', seleccion);
```

Si tienes dudas, puedes utilizar los comentarios. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo me sirvio, acertivo de verdad. Bendiciones